¿Porque MappingProfile no mapea la lista de mi Entity?
Estoy usando Entity Framework con MappingProfile para pasar las Entities a DTOs. Hasta ahora los mapeadores han funcionado, sin embargo me encuentro con una entity donde, en sus atributos tiene una lista de otra Entity relacional y al mappearla y retornarla en un endpoint la lista se mapea vacia.
La entidad TemplateVenusEntity es esta:
public class TemplateVenusEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long idTemplate { get; set; }

    public long idTemplateRemedy { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("idTemplateRemedy")]
    public virtual TemplateRemedyEntity infoTemplateRemedy { get; set; }

    public string title { get; set; }
    public string? description { get; set; }
    public string? resolution { get; set; }

    public long typeTemplate { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("typeTemplate")]
    public virtual  CatalogTypeTemplateVenusEntity infoTypeTemplate { get; set; }

    public string? imageError { get; set; }

    public long? typeError { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("typeError")]
    public virtual  CatalogTypeErrorReportEntity infoTypeError { get; set; }

    public long? idDevelopmentDepartament { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("idDevelopmentDepartament")]
    public virtual DevelopmentDepartamentEntity infoDevelopmentDepartament { get; set; }

    public long? status { get; set; }

    
    public virtual IEnumerable<TemplateDataRequiredEntity> dataRequired { get; set; }
}


La entity de la lista es esta:
public class TemplateDataRequiredEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long idConsecutive { get; set; }

    public long idTemplate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("idTemplate")]
    public virtual TemplateVenusEntity infoTemplate { get; set; }

    public long idRequiredData { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("idRequiredData")]
    public virtual  CatalogDataReportEntity infoDataRequired { get; set; }

    public long status { get; set; }
}


Ahora, mi Mapping Profile es este:
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile() {
        CreateMap<ReportEntity, ReportBasicDTO>() ;
        CreateMap<IEnumerable<ReportEntity>, List<ReportBasicDTO>>();
        CreateMap<CatalogDataReportEntity, CatalogDataReportDTO>();

        CreateMap<TemplateVenusEntity, TemplateVenusBasicDTO>();
        CreateMap<TemplateDataRequiredEntity, TemplateDataRequiredDTO>();  
        CreateMap<IEnumerable<TemplateDataRequiredEntity>, List<TemplateDataRequiredDTO>>();

        CreateMap<UserSoptecEntity, UserSoptecBasicDTO>(); 
       
    }
}



Respuesta de la API:
{
  "idTemplate": 290,
  "idTemplateRemedy": 420,
  "title": "Servidor caido-Sucursal sin sistema",
  "description": "Sucursal _SUCURSAL_ reporta no pueden acceder al sistema ya que tiene pantalla negra en todas las máquinas y no les permite ingresar. Se revisa el servidor el cual no responde  ping.\n\nTelefono de asesor: _TEL_ASESOR_",
  "resolution": "Debido a que el servidor no responde a ping, se accede por Ilo y la pantalla se encuentra en negro, se reinicia desde Ilo y se reinicia socket, se confirma con sucursal que operan de forma correcta.",
  "typeTemplate": 1,
  "imageError": "C:/VenusGS/ErrorImages/290.png",
  "typeError": 12,
  "idDevelopmentDepartament": null,
  "status": 1,
  "dataRequired": []
}


Pregunta: ¿Porque la lista se mapea vacia? En db si hay datos hijos, y al imprimir el count del atributo en consola la lista si tiene mas de un objeto, es en el mapeo en el que se vacia la lista
